# Aggregating and averaging data in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate

In my database, I have a list of people who live in many different zip codes. I would like to write a query that returns people grouped by zip code and also the average age of the people in each zip code. An example row in the result would be [83741, 38 years old].

How can this be done?

Cheers

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. How can we tell people's age?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT zip, avg(age)
    FROM people
    GROUP BY zip;